# Filtering an object array with duplicate titles and unique description?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I need to filter an object array that contains duplicate titles but the description is unique.
For e.g

```
[
    {
        "Title": "New York",
        "Description": "A healthy and modernized transit system"
    },
    {
        "Title": "New York",
        "Description": "changed transit system"
    },
    {
        "Title": "New York",
        "Description": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "Title": "New York",
        "Description": "abc"
    },
    {
        "Title": "chicago",
        "Description": "jdfjjfj"
    },
    {
        "Title": "chicago",
        "Description": "abcdfdjf"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the titles are duplicate whereas its description is unique.So can anybody please tell me how to filter this object array which filters out unique title and description being unique.

Basically the filtering should be as such that title comes first with its following unique descriptions.

Comment: Can you post what you expect this array to look like after it has been filtered? And also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JasonP: Thanks for your response :),I just wanted an array to have single titles followed with its multiple descriptions,just like how jgroenen mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rs = {};
$.each(objs, function(i, obj) {
  if (rs[obj.Title] === undefined) rs[obj.Title] = [];
  rs[obj.Title].push(obj.Description);
});
```

Check it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U6qu4/

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<=objs.length;i++){
for(var j=i+1;j<=objs.length;j++){
    if(objs[i].Title==objs[j].Title || objs[i].Description==objs[j].Description){
    //do some stuff to filter 
        objs.splice(j,1)  //it can be used to remove the matched element
    }
}
```

> 